# How to override the default terms update from converting Opportunity to Sales Order

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have added custom fields Terms and Ship via in opportunity and when i pass the value to sales order. It is replaced with default terms & ship via.

The following code I am using the pass the value from Opportunity to Sales Order

```
public virtual IEnumerable CreateSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter)
{

    PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<SOOrderEntry>((graph) =>
    {
        graph.RowInserted.AddHandler<SOOrder>((cache, args) =>
        {
            var soOrder = (SOOrder)args.Row;
            var soOrderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExtNV>(soOrder);

            foreach (CROpportunity opportunity in adapter.Get())
            {
                OppertunityExtn extOpprow = PXCache<CROpportunity>.GetExtension<OppertunityExtn>(opportunity);
                soOrderExt.UsrOpportunityID = opportunity.OpportunityID;
                soOrderExt.UsrCustomerContact = opportunity.ContactID;
                soOrderExt.UsrIsEmbroidery = extOpprow.UsrIsEmbroidery;
                soOrderExt.UsrIsPromo = extOpprow.UsrIsPromo;
                soOrderExt.UsrIsBlank = extOpprow.UsrIsBlank;
                soOrderExt.UsrIsService = extOpprow.UsrIsService;
                soOrderExt.UsrIsDigital = extOpprow.UsrIsDigital;
                soOrderExt.UsrIsSample = extOpprow.UsrIsSample;
                soOrderExt.UsrIsScreenPrint = extOpprow.UsrIsScreenPrint;
                soOrderExt.UsrIsRushJob = extOpprow.UsrIsRushJob;
                soOrderExt.UsrHardDate = extOpprow.UsrHardDate;
                soOrderExt.UsrIsInHandsDate = extOpprow.UsrIsInHandsDate;
                soOrderExt.UsrEventDate = extOpprow.UsrEventDate;
                soOrderExt.UsrEventDescription = extOpprow.UsrEventDescription;
                soOrderExt.UsrShipDate = extOpprow.UsrShipDate;
                soOrderExt.UsrHoldUntil = extOpprow.UsrHoldUntil;
                soOrderExt.UsrExactQuantityNeeded = extOpprow.UsrExactQuantityNeeded;
                soOrderExt.UsrIsNewCustomer = extOpprow.UsrIsNewCustomer;
                soOrderExt.UsrBatchShip = extOpprow.UsrBatchShip;
                soOrderExt.UsrInternalRef = extOpprow.UsrInternalRef;
                soOrder.ShipVia = extOpprow.UsrShipVia;
                soOrder.TermsID = extOpprow.UsrTerms;
                soOrder.FreightAmt = extOpprow.UsrFreightEstimate;

            }
        });
        graph.RowPersisting.AddHandler<SOOrder>((cache, args) =>
            {
                var soOrder = (SOOrder)args.Row;
                foreach (CROpportunity opportunity in adapter.Get())
                {
                    OppertunityExtn extOpprow = PXCache<CROpportunity>.GetExtension<OppertunityExtn>(opportunity);
                    soOrder.TermsID = extOpprow.UsrTerms;
                }

            });
    });
    return Base.createSalesOrder.Press(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Your problem is when converting an opportunity to a sales order, your custom fields (UsrTerms and ShipVia) values are reverted to the default values instead of keeping the values from opportunity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TermsID` is replaced after `SOOrder` row is inserted. You could refer below code of `OpportunityMaint.DoCreateSalesOrder`. That’s why it is replaced with value set at Customer’s level.

[image]

You should implement logic as below. And you could use similar approach for user fields as well.

```
public class OpportunityMaintPXExt : PXGraphExtension<OpportunityMaint>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<SOOrderEntry>((graph) =>
        {
            graph.RowUpdating.AddHandler<SOOrder>((sender, e) =>
            {
                SOOrder soData = e.NewRow as SOOrder;
                if (soData != null)
                {
                    if (sender.GetStatus(soData) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted)
                    {
                        CROpportunity opData = Base.Opportunity.Current;
                        CROpportunityPXExt opDataExt = PXCache<CROpportunity>.GetExtension<CROpportunityPXExt>(opData);

                        soData.TermsID = opDataExt.UsrTermsID;
                        soData.ShipVia = opDataExt.UsrShipVia;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Other User fields works fine in RowInserted Event and only Terms & ShipVia had issue. I thought it will update during Rowpersisting Event and it did not work.